# Browser Notification: not showing up

Tags: push-notification, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I seem to be following the code as suggested by Google Labs to create `serviceWorker` and have written the code for `pushing notifications`, yet it does not seem to be showing up. It seems like the push event from the server does reach the browser, however the `showNotification` function is just ignored.

```
// in sw.js
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
 console.log('Push Received'); // this shows up
 event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification('Hello World'));
 // tried  self.registration.showNotification('Hello World') but still does not show up
});
```

Further to check whether the `showNotification` works I have put the following in the `main.js`.

```
//in main.js
console.log(Notification.permission) // shows granted
if (Notification.permission == 'granted') {
 console.log('will show notification') // this gets logged
 navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(function(reg) {
   Console.log('reached here'); // this too gets logged
   reg.showNotification('Hello world!');
 });
```

Lastly I came across this site that some folks have used for testing

https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/

as well as

https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/

After permitting notifications from this site, I find no notifications appearing using the screen or the given curl command.

I have tried in both Chrome and Firefox and the results are the same. I am using Chrome 68.x and Firefox 61.x on Mac OS 10.13.6

I find that the site I am using has notifications enabled in the Chrome Settings (advanced section). Even clicking on the `secure` part of the address bar shows that notifications have been set to `allow`. Is there some other settings that I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 37):

It was such a silly error. Mac OS X has a notifications settings which was (I think default) set to 'DO NOT DISTURB`. Disabling that showed the push notifications. Thought other folks, like me, who may not have realised this should know.

Comment: I've just wasted an hour on this. Without this answer it would have been more. Thank you!

Comment: ah man!!!! I have just wasted 4 days. this is really silly

Comment: Ahaha god bless you, I was on sleep mode..

Answer (score 22):

Some additional advice for Windows 10 desktop users:

- *Not a -browser- notification* - The notifications caused by `self.registration.showNotification` will **not** show up in the browser as you might expect. These notifications show up in the Windows Action Center.
- *Focus Assist* - There is a "Focus Assist" setting in Windows that (analogous to the Apple setting mentioned above) determines whether notifications to the Action Center are silent or result in a toast. It does not mention Action Center.
- *More than one type of "Notification"* Just to confuse things, the Windows "Notifications" area is a different, but related feature. The Action Center has an icon in the Taskbar Notification Area. You can [read more here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/30031/windows-10-customize-taskbar-notification-area).
- *Dual Monitors* - If you have more than one monitor, you will only see the Action Center icon on the task bar of your primary monitor. Further, you will only see the Action Center toast on the primary monitor.
- *Existing notifications suppress toasts* - If the domain for your site is already listed in the Action Center, you won't see an additional toast for new messages. However, you will still see the item your site created in the Action Center. Clear that item, and your next notification *will* result in a toast.

Comment: I'm using showNotification method to, i see a lot of app notifications appears in browser , so what they use if they don't use this?

Comment: This! I had to right click at the bottom right corner of my screen and turn off focus assist. All of my notifications were being stored in the action center silently

Comment: "These notifications show up in the Windows Action Center."... and I was all the time looking at the browser window :)

Comment: On my windows 10 machine i also had to run the following command:

Get-AppxPackage | % { Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppxManifest.xml" -verbose }

(source:https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/win-10-notifications-not-working.html)

Answer (score 17):

Check the MacOS `notifications settings -> google chrome -> allow notification`

NOTE: only for Macbook users

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: **only for Macbook users**

Only for Macbook MacOS users `System Preferences --->  notifications & Focus -> google chrome -> allow notification`

[image]

then switch allow notification

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a reason I could not see the notifications either. but In windows I had to go to notification settings and for chrome it was disabled. In the browser allowed notifications was enabled.

Comment: screenshots would be nice

Answer (score 1):

As Ramulin said, in Windows 10 you need to enable chrome notifications, go to `Settings > System > Notifications & Actions > In Get notification and actions from these sender section select Google chrome.`